# How to deploy to different environment in Azure Devops using YAML file

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

Can you please help me with below.

I am building Azure Function app V3 and using Azure Devops YAML pipeline to build and deploy Azure function app and ARM infra to Dev environment. Now I want to deploy the same to UAT. I am not sure how to have different environment using YAML.
please find my `azure-pipeline.yml` file that I am using

```
name: $(Build.DefinitionName)-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

trigger:
  - dev
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipeline
      name: Pipeline
      type: git

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- name: Folder.BaseRepo # Location in repo where the templates are stored
  value: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Finance
- name: Folder.Templates # Location in repo where the templates are stored
  value: infrastructure

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build'
  jobs:
    - job: PublishTemplatesAndScripts
      displayName: 'Publish Templates and Scripts'
      steps:
        - template: 'publish-templates.yml@pipeline'
          parameters:
            templateFolder: '$(Folder.Templates)'
            artifactName: 'templates'
            pipelineRepository: pipeline
            pipelineRepositoryPath: pipeline
            
          
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: 'Restore dependencies'
          inputs:
            command: 'restore'
            projects: '$(Folder.BaseRepo)/Finance.sln'
            feedsToUse: 'select'
            vstsFeed: 'ac1301c4-6618-4824-a09e-0042d9871fb5/58ed1ece-4d06-46f7-b947-XXXX36281c4'
          enabled: true
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: 'Build function app'
          inputs:
            projects: '$(Folder.BaseRepo)/Finance.sln'
            command: 'build'
            arguments: '--configuration Release'
          enabled: true
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: 'Test function app'
          inputs:
            projects: '$(Folder.BaseRepo)/Finance.sln'
            command: 'test'
            arguments: '--configuration Release'
          enabled: false
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: 'Publish function app'
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishWebProjects: false
            projects: '$(Folder.BaseRepo)/src/Finance/Finance.csproj'
            arguments: '--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish --configuration Release'
          enabled: true
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          displayName: 'Publish function app output'
          inputs:
            targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/publish'
            artifact: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'pipeline'
          enabled: true

- stage: Development
  displayName: 'Development'
  jobs:
    - deployment: DevelopmentAzure
      displayName: 'Development Azure'
      environment: 'Development'
      #uses runtime expression
        strategy:
         runOnce:
           deploy:
             steps:
               - template: 'deploy-template.yml@pipeline'
                 parameters:
                   entryTemplateName: MyArm.json
                   templateParametersName: MyArm.dev.parameters.json
                   deploymentResourceManagerConnection: '$(Azure.NonProd.ResourceManagerConnection)'
                   deploymentSubscriptionIdentifier: '$(Azure.NonProd.SubscriptionId)'
                   resourceManagerConnection: '$(Azure.Dev.ResourceManagerConnection)'
                   subscriptionIdentifier: '$(Azure.Dev.SubscriptionId)'
                   resourceGroupName: '$(Resource_Group)'
                   outputVariablePrefix: AzureDeployment

    - deployment: DevelopmentFunctions
      displayName: 'DevelopmentFunctions'
      environment: 'Development'
      dependsOn: DevelopmentAzure
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
  
              - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: 'ServiceConnection-XXXXX-DevTest'
                  appType: 'functionApp'
                  appName: 'XXX-xxx-dev-funcapp'
                  package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/*.zip'
                  deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
                enabled: true
```

So what is the way to deploy it to Test environment. Do I need to create another yaml file with different trigger in same repo? or different stage in same yaml file and apply some condition on stages when UAT branch changes happen then deploy to only UAT stage only(not dev stage).

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another stage with some conditions for the deployment to Test environment.

Normally, you can set up a multi-stage pipeline that contains the main processes for your application, such as "Build", "Test" and "Deploy". And like release pipeline, you also can set a stage for each deployment environment in the same pipeline.

In your case, if you want that when new changes occur on the UAT branch, the deployment to Test environment can be triggered, you can set the condition like as below on the stage for Test environment.

```yaml
stages:
. . .
- stage: Test 
  displayName: 'Deploy to Test environment'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/UAT'))
. . .
```

For more details, you can see:

- [**Add stages, dependencies, & conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [**Multi-stage pipelines user experience**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops)